# Find Average Interval between Dates in a Pivot Table

Tags: vba, date, excel, pivot-table

I have a spreadsheet with order date data:

[image]

I need to find the average interval in days between each order date.  I have to both find a way to get past the blank cells in the row, and also take into account that some clients have 5-10 orders and some clients have 2 orders when calculating my average frequency (interval) between orders.

What I have so far:

```
Sub DateInt()
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim LastCol As Integer
Dim CurrentRow As Integer
Dim CurrentCol As Integer
Dim GrandT As String

GrandT = InputBox("Which column is the Grand Total in?", "Grand Total Column Letters")

Set CurrentSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
LastRow = CurrentSheet.Range(GrandT & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = CurrentSheet.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1

For CurrentRow = 5 To LastRow
    For CurrentCol = 2 To LastCol
        If Not CurrentSheet.Cells(CurrentRow, CurrentCol).Value = "" Then
            'Save date
            'Find next date in row
            'Subtract Dates to get interval and save interval in days
            'Save a running average of intervals
                'Maybe a running sum (SumDates) and a running divisor (NumOfDates)
        Else
        Next
    'Output average interval (SubDates / NumOfDates) in CurrentSheet.Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 1).Value
    Next

End Sub
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to do the loop inside the CurrentCol to LastCol loop:
Maybe something like:

```
NumOfDates = 0
'Loop
'Loop
NumOfDates = NumOfDates + 1   
Date & NumOfDates = CurrentCell.Value
If NumOfDates = 1 Then Next
Else
Interval = Date2 - Date1
TtlInterval = TtlInterval + Interval
Date2 = Date1
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing your question. I'll vote to reopen your question but you should still add more detail. Have you tried solving those individual problems that you commented on in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've got a winner here: (Even better with update)
[image]

```
Sub DateInt()
    Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim LastCol As Integer
    Dim CurrentRow As Integer
    Dim CurrentCol As Integer
    Dim GrandT As String
    Dim DateA As Date
    Dim DateB As Date
    Dim DateTtl As Integer
    Dim DateCount As Integer

    Set CurrentSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    LastRow = CurrentSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    LastCol = CurrentSheet.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Cells(4, LastCol + 1).Value = "Avg Interval"
    Cells(4, LastCol + 2).Value = "Days Since Last Order"
    Cells(4, LastCol + 3).Value = "Last Order Date"
    Cells(4, LastCol + 4).Value = "Last Order v Avg Order"

    For CurrentRow = 5 To LastRow
        Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol).Value = Date
        Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
        DateCount = 0
        DateTtl = 0
        DateC = DateAdd("d", 20, Date)

        For CurrentCol = 2 To LastCol
            If Cells(CurrentRow, CurrentCol).Value = "" Then
            Else
                If DateCount < 1 Then
                    DateA = Cells(CurrentRow, CurrentCol).Value
                Else
                    DateB = Cells(CurrentRow, CurrentCol).Value
                    DateTtl = DateDiff("d", DateA, DateB) + DateTtl

                    If DateValue(DateB) = DateValue(Date) Then
                    Else
                        DateA = DateB
                    End If
                End If

                DateCount = DateCount + 1
            End If
        Next CurrentCol

        Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 1).Value = DateTtl / DateCount
        Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 1).NumberFormat = "General"
        Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 2).Value = DateDiff("d", DateA, Date)
        Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 2).NumberFormat = "General"
        Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 3).Value = DateA
        Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 3).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
        Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 4).Value = Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 1).Value - Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 2).Value
        Cells(CurrentRow, LastCol + 4).NumberFormat = "#,##0_);[Red](#,##0)"
        Next CurrentRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code looks all right - you can try flipping some of your `If`-s if you want to save a few lines of code (you have `If ... Then <empty> Else <code> End If` in a few places).